# Javascript not entering a FOR loop inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, for-loop

I came here a few days ago asking for help on creating a grid of squares in JS/CSS.

A very helpful person came here and guided me on using two nested fors and *createElement('div');* to get the job done. However, his example was a code that went directly into doing that: http://jsfiddle.net/3x1kmcme/

I need the action to actually happen when the user clicks a button, using a .click() JQuery function. This is not working, and no error is being shown. I really did try going through the code itself, and even changed it, declared it beforehand as a variable, and went line by line to check where the error lies, it seems it's not entering the FOR loop, I could be wrong, of course.

Perhaps something obvious I'm missing?

```
var rows = 8,
    cells = 8,
    count = 0;

var i, j,
    top = 0,
    left = 0;

var boxWidth = 50,
    boxHeight = 50;    

var $canvas = $('#canvas');
var $fragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#btnstart").click(function () {
        function addBox(opts) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = opts.id;
            div.className = 'alive';
            div.style.top = opts.top + "px";
            div.style.left = opts.left + "px";
            $fragment.append(div);

        }
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j += 1) {
            top = j * boxHeight;
            for (i = 0; i < cells; i += 1) {
                count += 1;
                addBox({
                    count: count,
                    id: 'item' + i,
                    top: top,
                    left: i * boxWidth
                });
            }
        }
        $canvas.html($fragment);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you set `rows` and `cells`?

Comment: This might be a great opportunity for you to read, study and learn about JavaScript source level debugging.  Set a breakpoint in your code  prior to the for loop and then step through it.  That will tell you how your code path is being executed.

Comment: I didn't paste the whole code, will do then, edited!

Comment: You should empty the fragment at the beginning or end of the function. Otherwise, every time you click you'll duplicate all the boxes from the previous click.

Comment: http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x1kmcme/2/)

Not really sure what exactly the problem is. I added the following changes to the HTML

```
<div id="canvas"></div>

<input type='button' id='btnstart' value='Start' />
```

Comment: I have no idea, I went and made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1t6qc1a/1) out of the 3 files, and it does work in jsfiddle, but when I actually go to browser it does not (Chrome and I.E.)

Comment: @JoseRosales could you post your entire HTML? Looking at the fiddle you posted, the html is broken.

Comment: It was pretty much the entire HTML, but jsfiddle kept insisting I had no reason to put some tags. [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1t6qc1a/2/) has been updated with the entire html

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem AND the reason why it worked on JSFiddle. Even if I wrapped the JavaScript file in a Document.Ready function, I still had to put the scripts at the bottom of the page, just below the  tag.